# Data structure for O(log N) find and update, considering small L1 cache

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm currently working on an embedded device project where I'm running into performance problems. Profiling has located an O(N) operation that I'd like to eliminate.

I basically have two arrays `int A[N]` and `short B[N]`. Entries in `A` are unique and ordered by external constraints. The most common operation is to check if a particular value `a` appears in `A[]`. Less frequently, but still common is a change to an element of `A[]`. The new value is unrelated to the previous value.

Since the most common operation is the find, that's where `B[]` comes in. It's a sorted array of indices in `A[]`, such that `A[B[i]] < A[B[j]]` if and only if `i<j`. That means that I can find values in `A` using a binary search.

Of course, when I update `A[k]`, I have to find `k` in `B` and move it to a new position, to maintain the search order. Since I know the old and new values of `A[k]`, that's just a `memmove()` of a subset of `B[]` between the old and new position of `k`. This is the O(N) operation that I need to fix; since the old and new values of `A[k]` are essentially random I'm moving on average about <strike>N/2</strike> N/3 elements.

I looked into `std::make_heap` using `[](int i, int j) { return A[i] < A[j]; }` as the predicate. In that case I can easily make `B[0]` point to the smallest element of `A`, and updating `B` is now a cheap O(log N) rebalancing operation. However, I generally don't need the smallest value of A, I need to find if any given value is present. And that's now a O(N log N) search in `B`. (Half of my N elements are at heap depth log N, a quarter at (log N)-1, etc), which is no improvement over a dumb O(N) search directly in `A`.

Considering that `std::set` has O(log N) insert and find, I'd say that it should be possible to get the same performance here for update and find. But how do I do that? Do I need another order for `B`? A different type?

`B` is currently a `short [N]` because `A` and `B` together are about the size of my CPU cache, and my main memory is a lot slower. Going from 6*N to 8*N bytes would not be nice, but still acceptable if my find and update go to O(log N) both.

Comment: To be exact: moving 2 random elements will require moving N/3 elements on average, not N/2 (The elements before the first element and after the 2nd do not need to move). Nevertheless, it is a very interesting question!

Comment: maybe i didnt understand but i think you can keep your array sorted and do binary search. that would cost nlogn when you need to sort and log n when you need to search.

Comment: Approximately how big is N? Also, why is a Contains search O(N log N) instead of just O(N)? Searching in a heap is just O(N) as well (and you don't even have to do it in heap order)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree maybe?

Comment: @memo: That's why I stated that the order of `A` is externally imposed. I used `B` to create a second order which I do control. However, even if I could re-sort `A` instead of `B`, it would still be an O(N) operation (shift elements between `A[old]` and `A[new]` up or down one place). I'm aiming for O(log N).

Comment: Skiplists would meet both requirements, the log n search complexity and the memory tolerances("Going from 6*N to 8*N bytes")

Comment: Is there an issue with using a map instead of an array for B?

Comment: @harold: N is ~1000, cache is 8kB.

Comment: @VaughnCato: if you mean `std::map`, the easier and smaller solution would be `std::set<int> A`. But even that doesn't fit too well in 8kB cache.

Comment: if you could make a B+Tree it would very efficient because you would have all your data always sorted and search would cost log N, it would work if your tree doesnt change a lot so you wouldnt need to rebalance your tree, it would be a static structure, so if you can afford the memory maybe it could work.

Comment: I was thinking a std::set wasn't workable, since you needed to maintain a separate order for A.  But how about a custom allocator to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: How about a bloom filter and a linear search as fallback? It's pretty easy to tune the space/speed trade-off of that until it fits your usecase

Comment: @damienh: Skiplists look promising. If I understand them correctly, I'd make a `short B0[N]` bottom layer as I have now, and add additional layers `short B1[N/2]`, `short B2[N/4]` etc above `B0` ?

Comment: @VaughnCato: Eh, good point on the order of `A`, make that `std::set<short, sort_by_A> B`.

Comment: Implementing B[] as [tiered vector](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/papers/tiered-vector.pdf) allows O(log N) find (binary search), but O(sqrt(N)) update, which may be OK if updates are less frequent than searches. Space requirements are not much larger, than for simple array.

Comment: @memo: The relative frequency of updates is far more than `1/N`, so I can't just optimize for find. The current implementation, with the sorted array `B` does exactly that. That's why the O(N) updates hurt me. If updates had a relative frequency less than `1/N`, an O(N) update wouldn't matter in the big picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the only operations are (1) check if value 'a' belongs to A and (2) update values in A, why don't you use a **hash table** in place of the sorted array B? Especially if A does not grow or shrink in size and the values only change this would be a much better solution. A hash table does not require significantly more memory than an array. (Alternatively, B should be changed not to a heap but to a binary search tree, that could be self-balancing, e.g. a splay tree or a red-black tree. However, trees require *extra memory* because of the left- and right-pointers.)

A practical solution that grows memory use from 6N to 8N bytes is to aim for exactly 50% filled hash table, i.e. use a hash table that consists of an array of 2N shorts. I would recommend implementing the **Cuckoo Hashing** mechanism (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). Read the article further and you find that you can get load factors above 50% (i.e. push memory consumption down from 8N towards, say, 7N) by using more hash functions. "**Using just three hash functions increases the load to 91%.**"

From Wikipedia:

> A study by Zukowski et al. has shown that cuckoo hashing is much
>   faster than chained hashing for **small, cache-resident hash tables** on
>   modern processors. Kenneth Ross has shown bucketized versions of
>   cuckoo hashing (variants that use buckets that contain more than one
>   key) to be faster than conventional methods also for large hash
>   tables, when space utilization is high. The performance of the
>   bucketized cuckoo hash table was investigated further by Askitis,
>   with its performance compared against alternative hashing schemes.

Comment: But in order to achieve good performance with a hash table, the size of it (the hash table) needs to be ~*2-4 of number of elements (load balance)... Otherwise - collisions will be too frequent, and it will decay to `O(n)` both search and update.

Comment: Yes, a hash table takes more memory than a simple array regardless of how the hash table is implemented... Question: do you have any statistics on how often when you query for the presence of 'a' it IS present and how often it is NOT present --- which one of the cases is more common or are they both as common?

Comment: @antti.huima: With `N=1000` I'm looking at 60-90% presence. Depends a bit on data sets used and exact user query, but 2:1 is a reasonable approximation of the ratio.

Comment: Hmm ok then it doesn't make sense really to optimize the algorithm for either one of the cases

Comment: Ok, I think Cuckoo Hashing would solve this with only small memory footprint increase (say, to 7N with a 66% load factor on the hash table). See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, still working on this, and I can't figure out why cuckoo hashing should be cache-efficient. It seems to use random cache lines, but only parts of them. The bucket solution appears quite reasonable (especially with one bucket = one cache line) but that makes the logic even harder.

Comment: At least it should be cache-efficient generally  because it can achieve very high load factors, so the whole hash table requires less memory as a whole. This is in relation to other hash table mechanisms, e.g. chained hashing  as mentioned in the text.

Comment: It turns out that the actual implementation has a subtle edge case; if both hash functions return the same value you have a cycle of length 1 which you have to detect. We were lucky to find this bug in review; on our test set this didn't occur. Also, for high load tables we found "Hopscotch Hashing" as an alternative.

Comment: @MSalters According to Wikipedia, "In one of the commonly used variants of the algorithm, the hash table is split into two smaller tables of equal size, and each hash function provides an index into one of these two tables." If cuckoo hashing is thus organized you can't have a collision between the two hash values as they point to two separate spaces.

Comment: @antti.huima: A similar effect can be used by using one hash function which returns only even values, and another which uses only odd values. If all your cycles are of even length, you obviously can't have the edge case of a cycle of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` usually provides the *O(log(n))* insert and delete by using a binary search tree. This unfortunately uses 3*N space for most pointer based implementations. Assuming word sized data, 1 for data, 2 for pointers to left and right child on each node.

If you have some constant N and can guarantee that `ceil(log2(N))` is less than half the word size you can use a fixed length array of tree nodes each 2*N size. Use 1 for data, 1 for the indexes of the two child nodes, stored as the upper and lower half of the word. Whether this would let you use a self balancing binary search tree of some manner depends on your N and word size. For a 16 bit system you only get N = 256, but for 32 its 65k.

Comment: I can indeed live with N<65536, datasets that size would require a dataset exceeding 256MB. My cheap embedded processor with its 8kB cache isn't going to survive that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have limited N, can't you use `std::set<short, cmp, pool_allocator> B` with [Boost's `pool_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.pool_allocator)?

Comment: At least with libstdc++ 4.6.3, I've found that std::set allocates at least 20*N bytes.

Comment: Agree with Vaughn, `std::set` is going to allocate at least two pointers. I could roll my own, using Adam's idea, but building a red-black tree using `short` as a substitute for pointers sounds hard.