# Fast merge of sorted subsets of 4K floating-point numbers in L1/L2

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm, assembly

What is a fast way to merge sorted subsets of an array of up to 4096 32-bit floating point numbers on a modern (SSE2+) x86 processor?

Please assume the following:

- The size of the entire set is at maximum 4096 items
- The size of the subsets is open to discussion, but let us assume between 16-256 initially
- All data used through the merge should preferably fit into L1
- The L1 data cache size is 32K. 16K has already been used for the data itself, so you have 16K to play with
- All data is already in L1 (with as high degree of confidence as possible) - it has just been operated on by a sort
- All data is 16-byte aligned
- We want to try to minimize branching (for obvious reasons)

Main criteria of feasibility: faster than an in-L1 LSD radix sort.

I'd be very interested to see if someone knows of a reasonable way to do this given the above parameters! :)

Comment: I am not sure this fits the SO criteria, in particular I believe that it falls within the 'Too localized' criterion for closing a question. On the other hand, I will be interested in possible approaches... so I am not voting to close  :)

Comment: Okay, I see... for future reference, would any other SX site be more appropriate?

Comment: While the question itself is pretty localized, I expect that any answers might be applicable to a wider audience... if any are forthcoming that is.

Comment: Disagree with David; this is similar in scope to [my earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551808/data-structure-for-olog-n-find-and-update-considering-small-l1-cache).  I believe such questions add more value than "which API function do I need for X" which is usually solved by Google "X site:msdn.microsoft.com" and the likes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a very naive way to do it. (Please excuse any 4am delirium-induced pseudo-code bugs ;)

```
//4x sorted subsets
data[4][4] = {
  {3, 4, 5, INF},
  {2, 7, 8, INF},
  {1, 4, 4, INF},
  {5, 8, 9, INF}
}

data_offset[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0}

n = 4*3

for(i=0, i<n, i++):
  sub = 0
  sub = 1 * (data[sub][data_offset[sub]] > data[1][data_offset[1]])
  sub = 2 * (data[sub][data_offset[sub]] > data[2][data_offset[2]])
  sub = 3 * (data[sub][data_offset[sub]] > data[3][data_offset[3]])

  out[i] = data[sub][data_offset[sub]]
  data_offset[sub]++
```

**Edit:**
With AVX2 and its gather support, we could compare up to 8 subsets at once.

**Edit 2:**
Depending on type casting, it might be possible to shave off 3 extra clock cycles per iteration on a Nehalem (mul: 5, shift+sub: 4)

```
//Assuming 'sub' is uint32_t
sub = ... << ((data[sub][data_offset[sub]] > data[...][data_offset[...]]) - 1)
```

**Edit 3:**
It may be possible to exploit out-of-order execution to some degree, especially as K gets larger, by using two or more `max` values:

```
max1 = 0
max2 = 1
max1 = 2 * (data[max1][data_offset[max1]] > data[2][data_offset[2]])
max2 = 3 * (data[max2][data_offset[max2]] > data[3][data_offset[3]])
...
max1 = 6 * (data[max1][data_offset[max1]] > data[6][data_offset[6]])
max2 = 7 * (data[max2][data_offset[max2]] > data[7][data_offset[7]])

q = data[max1][data_offset[max1]] < data[max2][data_offset[max2]]

sub = max1*q + ((~max2)&1)*q
```

**Edit 4:**

Depending on compiler intelligence, we can remove multiplications altogether using the ternary operator:

```
sub = (data[sub][data_offset[sub]] > data[x][data_offset[x]]) ? x : sub
```

**Edit 5:**

In order to avoid costly floating point comparisons, we could simply `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>()` the data, as this would result in an integer compare.

Another possibility is to utilize SSE registers as these are not typed, and explicitly use integer comparison instructions.

This works due to the operators `< > ==` yielding the same results when interpreting a float on the binary level.

**Edit 6:**

If we unroll our loop sufficiently to match the number of values to the number of SSE registers, we could stage the data that is being compared.

At the end of an iteration we would then re-transfer the register which contained the selected maximum/minimum value, and shift it.

Although this requires reworking the indexing slightly, it may prove more efficient than littering the loop with `LEA`'s.

Comment: This will obviously eject 4*subsets bytes of data, sans padding, from L1, but should be negligible

Comment: The '<' implies a compare and branch in the assembly code, if that's what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: afaik "cmp" is not a branching instruction. obviously you will have one branch for the loop conditional, but you can unroll it to lessen this effect. the CPU might have problems with OO execution though, as there's a full data dependency throughout the loop

Comment: This is a good answer.  I thought the equations would result in compare and branch, but gcc optimizes to cmp and setl (set if less) which apparently does not mess up the pipeline.

Comment: yeah, the instruction stream will be decoded in the same manner no matter what `cmp` sets in `EFLAGS`, and thus the pipeline will not stall :)

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a research topic, but I did find [this paper](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/wads05.pdf) which discusses minimizing branch mispredictions using d-way merge sort.

Comment: I would maintain that an insertion d-way mergesort is suboptimal as compared to a non-branching linear merge if we are operating solely in L1. interesting read, though :)

Answer (score 3):

SIMD sorting algorithms have already been studied in detail. The paper [Efficient Implementation of Sorting on Multi-Core SIMD CPU Architecture](http://pcl.intel-research.net/publications/sorting_vldb08.pdf) describes an efficient algorithm for doing what you describe (and much more).

The core idea is that you can reduce merging two arbitrarily long lists to merging blocks of *k* consecutive values (where *k* can range from 4 to 16): the first block is `z[0] = merge(x[0], y[0]).lo`. To obtain the second block, we know that the leftover `merge(x[0], y[0]).hi` contains `nx` elements from `x` and `ny` elements from `y`, with `nx+ny == k`. But `z[1]` cannot contain elements from both `x[1]` and `y[1]`, because that would require `z[1]` to contain more than `nx+ny` elements: so we just have to find out which of `x[1]` and `y[1]` needs to be added. The one with the lower first element will necessarily appear first in `z`, so this is simply done by comparing their first element. And we just repeat that until there is no more data to merge.

Pseudo-code, assuming the arrays end with a `+inf` value:

```
a := *x++
b := *y++
while not finished:
    lo,hi := merge(a,b)
    *z++ := lo
    a := hi
    if *x[0] <= *y[0]:
        b := *x++
    else:
        b := *y++
```

(note how similar this is to the usual scalar implementation of merging)

The conditional jump is of course not necessary in an actual implementation: for example, you could conditionally swap `x` and `y` with an `xor` trick, and then read unconditionally `*x++`.

`merge` itself can be implemented with a bitonic sort. But if *k* is low, there will be a lot of inter-instruction dependencies resulting in high latency. Depending on the number of arrays you have to merge, you can then choose *k* high enough so that the latency of `merge` is masked, or if this is possible interleave several two-way merges. See the paper for more details.

---

**Edit**: Below is a diagram when *k* = 4. All asymptotics assume that *k* is fixed.

- The big gray box is merging two arrays of size *n* = *m* * *k* (in the picture, *m* = 3).

  [image]

  1. We operate on blocks of size *k*.
  2. The "whole-block merge" box merges the two arrays block-by-block by comparing their first elements. This is a linear time operation, and it doesn't consume memory because we stream the data to the rest of the block. The performance doesn't really matter because the latency is going to be limited by the latency of the "merge4" blocks.
  3. Each "merge4" box merges two blocks, outputs the lower *k* elements, and feeds the upper *k* elements to the next "merge4". Each "merge4" box performs a bounded number of operations, and the number of "merge4" is linear in *n*.
  4. So the time cost of merging is linear in *n*. And because "merge4" has a lower latency than performing 8 serial non-SIMD comparisons, there will be a large speedup compared to non-SIMD merging.
- Finally, to extend our 2-way merge to merge many arrays, we arrange the big gray boxes in classical divide-and-conquer fashion. Each level has complexity linear in the number of elements, so the total complexity is O(*n* log (*n* / *n0*)) with *n0* the initial size of the sorted arrays and *n* is the size of the final array.

  [image: diagram]

Comment: I think you mean a bitonic/sorting network `merge` is efficient when the subset length <= 16, no?

Comment: Yes, but the important point is that you can use this primitive as a building block in order to efficiently merge arbitrarily large subsets.

Comment: But the sorting network size explodes as the number of subsets increase, right? I.e. it will most likely be beaten even by a heap on non-GPU processors

Comment: Not at all. `merge` is just a fixed-size building block, and then it is used to merge the full subset in O(*n*) time and no memory apart from that used by the output: look at the pseudocode I posted for merging two subsets and you will see there is no explosion. For merging many subsets, the total complexity is O(*N* log *N/N0*) where *N0* is the original size of the subsets and *N* is the size of the final merged array, which is optimal. This algorithm is claimed to be state-of-the-art by Intel itself, so calling it *efficient* is a bit of an understatement.

Comment: for `k=4`: `a,b,c,d=...; lo,hi1=merge(a,b); lo,hi2=merge(b,lo); lo,hi3=(c,lo), lo,hi4=(d,lo); output lo; lo,hi5=merge(hi1,hi2); lo,hi6=merge(lo,hi3);` and so on... unless I have completely misunderstood your explanation and/or you can auspex the data distribution in the subsets, this is provably suboptimal for any significant `k`

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer that comes to mind is a standard N-way merge using a heap. That'll be O(N log k). The number of subsets is between 16 and 256, so the worst case behavior (with 256 subsets of 16 items each) would be 8N.

Cache behavior should be ... reasonable, although not perfect. The heap, where most of the action is, will probably remain in the cache throughout. The part of the output array being written to will also most likely be in the cache.

What you have is 16K of data (the array with sorted subsequences), the heap (1K, worst case), and the sorted output array (16K again), and you want it to fit into a 32K cache. Sounds like a problem, but perhaps it isn't. The data that will most likely be swapped out is the front of the output array after the insertion point has moved. Assuming that the sorted subsequences are fairly uniformly distributed, they should be accessed often enough to keep them in the cache.

Comment: just to clarify... which variable do you refer to when you say `k`? the complexity ought to be O(n log n), right, since you would have to insert all items into the heap before starting to extract them?

yeah there's bound to be some memory spill if you use intermediate/temporary data. of course it might not be possible to achieve a perfect fit into L1/32K, but it's a guideline at the least... :)

Comment: `k` is the number of sorted subsequences. The heap contains `k` entries--the lowest item from each of the subsequences. The time to insert or remove an item is O(log k). Every item ends up being inserted into the heap, but not all at once. So the complexity is O(n log k). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Comment: yes, in that case it makes sense and is O(n log k) I'd just misunderstood you slightly in terms of the insertion process. :) don't heaps branch (cause pipeline stalls) like crazy, though?

Comment: Certainly, maintaining a heap requires some comparisons and branches. Whether that causes pipeline stalls is going to depend the branch prediction logic. The real question is whether the reduced complexity of the merge algorithm (O(n log k) as opposed to the radix sort's O(n * keylength)) more than compensates for any negative effects of the branching. That's something you'll have to test.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge int arrays (expensive) branch free.

```
typedef unsigned uint;
typedef uint* uint_ptr;

void merge(uint*in1_begin, uint*in1_end, uint*in2_begin, uint*in2_end, uint*out){

  int_ptr in [] = {in1_begin, in2_begin};
  int_ptr in_end [] = {in1_end, in2_end};

  // the loop branch is cheap because it is easy predictable
  while(in[0] != in_end[0] && in[1] != in_end[1]){
    int i = (*in[0] - *in[1]) >> 31;
    *out = *in[i];
    ++out;
    ++in[i];
  }

  // copy the remaining stuff ...
}
```

Note that (*in[0] - *in[1]) >> 31 is equivalent to *in[0] - *in[1] < 0 which is equivalent to *in[0] < *in[1]. The reason I wrote it down using the bitshift trick instead of

```
int i = *in[0] < *in[1];
```

is that not all compilers generate branch free code for the < version.

Unfortunately you are using floats instead of ints which at first seems like a showstopper because I do not see how to realabily implement *in[0] < *in[1] branch free. However, on most modern architectures you interprete the bitpatterns of positive floats (that also are no NANs, INFs or such strange things) as ints and compare them using < and you will still get the correct result. Perhaps you extend this observation to arbitrary floats.

Comment: I think `<` causing non-branching code to be generated can be remedied by some good old asm ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple merge kernel to merge K lists:

```
float *input[K];
float *output;

while (true) {
  float min = *input[0];
  int min_idx = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < K; i++) {
    float v = *input[i];
    if (v < min) {
      min = v;     // do with cmov
      min_idx = i; // do with cmov
    }
  }
  if (min == SENTINEL) break;
  *output++ = min;
  input[min_idx]++;
}
```

There's no heap, so it is pretty simple.  The bad part is that it is O(NK), which can be bad if K is large (unlike the heap implementation which is O(N log K)).  So then you just pick a maximum K (4 or 8 might be good, then you can unroll the inner loop), and do larger K by cascading merges (handle K=64 by doing 8-way merges of groups of lists, then an 8-way merge of the results).